# problem "extending" item renderer : duplicate content generated

Tags: layout, sales, renderer

I try to overload sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml to modify order printing format

In my layout.xml I defined :

```
<sales_order_view>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>

    <sales_order_print>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sales/order_print" name="sales.order.print" template="sales/order/print.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_print>
```

When I generate the order print view, my new renderer is applied, but the generated page displays the order summary 2 times…

An idea why?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2):

it works with :

```
<sales_order_print>
    <reference name="sales.order.print">
        <action method="setTemplate"><value>sales/order/print.phtml</value></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>quotemodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>quotemodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</sales_order_print>
```

You have to use `<reference>` instead of `<block>`, to apply the methods on the existing block. `<block>` always creates a new block.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, so that this question does not appear as "unanswered" anymore.